# angular dir-paginate paginate-id error

Tags: angularjs, pagination, dirpagination

i have a list and within that list i have a new list that needs to be paginated. To make sure that each inner list know which list they belong to i use: `pagination-id`:

```
<div class="list-group bg-white m-none b-t">
<span dir-paginate="module in category.organization_has_modules | itemsPerPage:10 | filter:search"
      pagination-id="category.id">
<a ui-sref="app.library_assign({module_id:module.module.id})"
   class="list-group-item"
   ng-if="module.is_active != 0">
    <i class="fa fa-fw {{module.module.module_type.icon}}"></i>
    {{module.module.name}}
    <span class="pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
    </span>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</a>
</span>
<dir-pagination-controls class="pull-right" pagination-id="category.id"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

When i run this i sadly get the following error message:

```
error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '__currentPage' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the expression [103__currentPage] starting at [__currentPage].
```

if i run it without the `pagination-id` it runs fine however it is unable to differ the different lists which means all the pages change when i change it in one of the lists.

Does anyone have any idea of what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apprently a bug with the id being a number. The parser in dirPagination.js line 206 does not accept numbers and the regex created to replace any numbers is apprently not working. So instead of using a number i used a string.